# Meaning of "no more than" in the sentence

Tags: comparative-constructions

What does 'no more than' mean in this sentence?

> **No more than** European society before 1848 felt the revolutionary atmosphere enveloping and pressing it from all sides - [*source here*](https://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/works/1856/04/14.htm).

Is it...

1. No other society felt as much pressure as the pre-1848 European society.
2. No other society felt as much pressure as the post-1848 European society.

Comment: Source? Or did you write this? It does not make any sense.

Comment: @user3169 It's been taken from somewhere. But I don't want people to give a biased answer. I'll share the source tomorrow.

Comment: When you provide a link/source, you are likely to get *appropriate* answers rather than biased. So, do that.

Comment: But then many 'meanings' depend on the context. Using the same words, without having any context, wont get you precise answers. Thanks for the source though.

Comment: This question is actually impossible to answer without the additional context Maulik asked for.  Luckily, it's answerable now :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's easier to understand that part of his speech in context.

> That social revolution, it is true, was no novelty invented in 1848. Steam, electricity, and the self-acting mule were revolutionists of a rather more dangerous character than even citizens Barbés, Raspail and Blanqui. But, although the atmosphere in which we live, weighs upon every one with a 20,000 lb. force, do you feel it? **No more than** European society before 1848 felt the revolutionary atmosphere enveloping and pressing it from all sides.

Here is how I read it:

> ...
>   *But, although the atmosphere in which we live, weighs upon every one with a 20,000 lb. force, do you feel it?*
>   (The audience: No, we don't feel that!)
>
> *No more than European society before 1848 felt the revolutionary atmosphere enveloping and pressing it from all sides.*
>   (= We don't feel that pressure any more than "European society before 1848" felt the revolutionary atmosphere, which was enveloping and pressing it from all sides.)

In plain English:

- We don't feel the huge pressure of the atmosphere (that we live in).
- European society before 1848 didn't feel the revolutionary atmosphere, either.